# regexp to match only one occurrence followed by two digits

Tags: regex

I want to replace the `,` by a `.` if both the following cases are true:

- `,` should be present only once in the string
- `,` should be followed by a maximum of two digits

These are OK: `1 000 000,51`, `1.000,9`

These are not: `9,523,036.11`, `1,000`

My evolution so far: https://regex101.com/r/njuKtb/1

Comment: I would use `([\d\s]+,)?[\d]{1,2}` https://regex101.com/r/njuKtb/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex for search:

```
^([^,]*),(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))(?!.*,)
```

And use this replacement:

```
$1.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/njuKtb/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^([^,]*)`: Match 0 or more non-comma characters at the start
- `,`: Match literal comma
- `(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))`: Match 1 or 2 digits not followed by another digit
- `(?!.*,)`: Make sure we don't have comma ahead

---

Alternatively use this for search:

```
^([^,]*),(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))([^,\n]*)$
```

and replace by:

```
$1.$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
/^(?!^[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*)(?:[^,\n]*),(?=\d{1,2}\D*$)/m
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMEy1D/3)

Which is:

```
^                            Start of string or line                 
(?!^[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*,[^,\n]*) Only matches lines with a single ','
(?:[^,\n]*)                  Suck up the LH before the ,
,                            The , 
(?=\d{1,2}\D*$)              no more than two \d before end of the line
```